# ’t Hooft anomaly matching and massless baryons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies, baryons

In Lectures on [Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) by David Tong there is statement (section 5.6.3 The Vafa-Witten-Weingarten Theorems), that:

> To invoke the full power of ’t Hooft anomaly matching, we needed to assume that any baryon that contains a massive quark is itself massive.

Why it is so important? If baryons are fermions and are massles, one must include their contribution to anomaly in IR. What is problem if one will not assume massive nature of baryons?